SQLchemy: caught in a loop between constraint relationship class already existing when trying to create it, but not existing when I try and drop it
I have an upserting python function (for psql) I took from this website: How to upsert pandas DataFrame to PostgreSQL table?
It works fine when I run it once, which creates a new table. But if I run it again on the same table to upsert, I get an error at this stage:
query_pk = f"""
ALTER TABLE "{table_name}" DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS unique_constraint_for_upserting;
ALTER TABLE "{table_name}" ADD CONSTRAINT unique_constraint_for_upserting UNIQUE ({columns_sql_txt});
"""
engine.execute(query_pk)

... saying the Constraint already exists:
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable) relation "unique_constraint_for_upserting" already exists

[SQL: 
    ALTER TABLE "fixtures" DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS unique_constraint_for_upserting;
    ALTER TABLE "fixtures" ADD CONSTRAINT unique_constraint_for_upserting UNIQUE ("date", "time", "league", "home", "away", "country");

yet if I run it without the IF EXISTS (and no other changes):
query_pk = f"""
ALTER TABLE "{table_name}" DROP CONSTRAINT unique_constraint_for_upserting;
ALTER TABLE "{table_name}" ADD CONSTRAINT unique_constraint_for_upserting UNIQUE ({columns_sql_txt});
"""
engine.execute(query_pk)

I get this error:
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject) constraint "unique_constraint_for_upserting" of relation "fixtures" does not exist

[SQL: 
    ALTER TABLE "fixtures" DROP CONSTRAINT unique_constraint_for_upserting;
    ALTER TABLE "fixtures" ADD CONSTRAINT unique_constraint_for_upserting UNIQUE ("date", "time", "league", "home", "away", "country");
    ]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)

So on the one hand the constraint exists, but also it doesn't?

What happens if you try the same thing without SQLAlchemy? Just a plain psql client.

I can't reproduce this with SQLAlchemy 2.0

@Schwern same error if I run it in a psql client

I think I worked it out - the issue was that in testing I made another table with the same constrain name. On reading the docs the constraints have to be globally unique. So because it already existed somewhere else, it was not allowing me to make a new one, even though for that specific table it didn't have one

@Lord_Verulam Yes, constraint names are global, and databases are a shared resource. To avoid this in such a situation like testing where you're making and destroying a lot of things, append a little bit of randomness to table names, and prefix constraints with the table name.

will do! Thank you :)
